# Multiple table outer join when any one table may have results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple organizational (6) tables that have data about membership. An individual may be a member on 0 or more organizations. This is an example of common fields from table schema (example only not really) idIndividual,name,address
I want the idIndividual and address for a given name

```
Select name, address,idIndividual 
from tbl1,tbl2,tbl3,tbl4,tbl5,tbl6
where name = 'FOO'
```

The person may be in none or all of the tables, I'm lost with this one, any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Will there be multiple distinct `idIndividual` for `name = 'FOO'` ?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Crazy stuff like sample data, expected results, ... .

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` instead

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT name, address,idIndividual 
FROM tbl1
UNION
SELECT name, address,idIndividual 
FROM tbl2
UNION
SELECT name, address,idIndividual 
FROM tbl3
UNION
SELECT name, address,idIndividual 
FROM tbl4
UNION
SELECT name, address,idIndividual 
FROM tbl5
UNION
SELECT name, address,idIndividual 
FROM tbl6
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE name = 'FOO'
```